# Trying to create a folder with variables from Read-Host

Tags: powershell

I've built a tiny little script to create folders from information that is in a .csv but the folder naming convention could be different every time.

So I was wondering if there was a way I could have the variables pre-saved and just call them when I come to create the folders, i.e I could have 732881-English or English732881 depending on what I write in the read-host, the only problem is it wont print in the file name i've tried using `${variable) ${variable}` and nothing appears to work

I've attatched a similiar code here to what I am using

```
Import-Csv "\\Desktop\Powershell Testing\staffdata.csv"
$students = Import-Csv "\\Desktop\Powershell Testing\staffdata.csv"

foreach($object in $students) {

    $id = $object.'Roll Number'
    $subject = $object.'Subject'

    $foldername = Read-Host "Enter Folder Name"

    New-Item -Path "\\Desktop\Powershell Testing\ExamHomes\$foldername" -ItemType Directory
}
```

Comment: "nothing appears to work" - but what _happens_? Do you get an error? Folders created with the wrong name? Please be mindful that only you can see your screen :-)

Comment: Hi Mathias, first post so bare with me :)

So lets say I set $foldername = Test$id

It would create a folder called Test732881

But if I have the Read-Host line and I type in Test$id it would just create a folder called Test, it would'nt print the variable if that makes sense

No errors just unable to get it working how I would like it to

Basically I want to be able to type the structure for the folder like HomeArea$id but on another occasion I may want to be able to create a folder called ReportFolder$id but have the ability of just typing in the structure with variables

Comment: No worries, we all start somewhere :) `$foldername = Test$id` should throw an error (unless you've defined a function named `Test$id`) - could it be that you're not quoting your strings properly? Try `$readHostInput = Read-Host "Enter folder name"; $foldername = "${readHostInput}${id}"`

Comment: `Read-Host` will take variables as literal strings. You can create your own function for this as Mathias pointed out. There is also a workaround for this, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837808/can-read-host-accept-a-variable-as-input

Comment: I've had a bit of a play around and used this 

$value = Read-Host 
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($value)
$id = "873293"
$name = "John Smith"

New-Item -Path "\\Desktop\Variable Print\$value" -ItemType Directory

Basically from here I would like it so when I am prompted I can create the folder by typing in $id-$name or on another occasion I could type $name-$id so It will be different depending on how I enter it, I've tried a combination of both replies and still can't get it to function.

Maybe I am missing something or is it just not possible to do so?

Comment: So basically in my .csv file I could have numerous collums, declare them as variables in powershell and just call which elements I want to use - so can use them in different scenarios, so in the case I just need $firstname$id to be the folder name and then on another occassion I might just need $department$firstname just so I have the freedom of typing in the format, as I am only using it I know all the names of the variables so can call on them